# php time() and microtime() do sometimes not concord

Tags: php, time, microtime

While logging some data using microtime() (using PHP 5), I encountered some values that seemed slightly out of phase in respect to the timestamp of my log file, so I just tried to compare the output of time() and microtime() with a simple script (usleep is just here in order to limit the data output):

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
    $microtime = microtime();
    $time = time();
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", $microtime);
    if ((int)$sec > $time) {
        echo $time . ' : ' . $microtime . '<br>';
    }
    usleep(50000);
}
?>
```

Now, as $microtime is declared before $time, I expect it to be smaller, and nothing should ever be output; however, this obviously is not the case, and every now and then, $time is smaller than the seconds returned from microtime(), as in this example (truncated) output:

```
1344536674 : 0.15545100 1344536675
1344536675 : 0.15553900 1344536676
1344536676 : 0.15961000 1344536677
1344536677 : 0.16758900 1344536678
```

Now, this is just a small gap; however, I have observed some series where the difference is (quite) more than a second... so, how is this possible?

Comment: Could you tell me the outcome of some big upcoming matches? I'm want to place some bets ;)

Comment: Can you tell us what OS you are using, what version of PHP this is happening in, and what version of libc/glibc PHP was compiled with?  `microtime` works differently on Windows than it does on Linux, but both functions on Linux rely on C functions to get this info so likely this isn't really a PHP issue.  I ran your code on PHP 5.4.5 and no time values were output (meaning time was always greater than or equal to microtime [as would be expected]).

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the implementations of [`time`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1613) and [`microtime`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/microtime.c#L51), you see they're radically different:

- `time` just calls the C [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) function.
- `microtime` has *two* implementations: If the C function [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) is available (which it should be on a Linux system), it is called straight-forward. Otherwise [they pull of some acrobatics to use rusage](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/microtime.c#L108) to calculate the time.

Since the C `time` call is only precise up to a second, it may also intentionally use a low-fidelity time source.

Furthermore, on modern x86_64 systems, [both C functions can be implemented *without a system call* by looking into certain CPU registers](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0702.0/0082.html). If you're on a multi-core system, these registers may not exactly match across cores, and that could be a reason.

Another potential reason for the discrepancies is that NTPd(a time-keeping daemon) or some other user-space process is changing the clock. Normally, these kinds of effects should be avoided by [`adjtime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/adjtime).

All of these rationales are pretty esoteric. To further debug the problem, you should:

- Determine OS and CPU architecture <sub>(hint: and tell us!)</sub>
- Try to [force the process on one core](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core)
- Stop any programs that are (or may be) adjusting the system time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed hints. This definitely seems to be related to the OS, as it does occur on the two windows 7 machines I have at hand, but apparently not on the linux box of my hoster... 
As this might be a rather difficult problem to address, I guess I will just try to find some alternative to the usage of microtime...

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact that microtime() uses floating point numbers, and therefore [rounding errors may occur](http://php.net/language.types.float).

You can specify [floating point numbers' precision in php.ini](http://php.net/precision)