# PHP `time_sleep_until()` does not sleep until specified time

Tags: php, datetime

On my machine, the PHP program

```
<?php
$now= time();
echo "Now:        ".$now."\n";
$waituntil= $now+5;
echo "Wait until: ".$waituntil."\n";
time_sleep_until($waituntil);
echo "Now:        ".time()."\n";
?>
```

produces an output such as

```
Now:        1492614718
Wait until: 1492614723
Now:        1492614722
```

Now I am wondering why the `time_sleep_until` function did not wait until the specified time (it always continues one second before the specified time).

How can I achieve that the program waits until the specified linux timestamp?

EDIT:
I added `microtime(true)` and now get the following result:

```
<?php
$now= time();
$nowmicro= microtime(true);
echo "Now:        ".$now."\n";
echo "Now micro:  ".$nowmicro."\n";
$waituntil= $now+5;
echo "Wait until: ".$waituntil."\n";
time_sleep_until($waituntil);

$now= time();
$nowmicro= microtime(true);
echo "Now:        ".$now."\n";
echo "Now micro:  ".$nowmicro."\n";
?>
```

produces

```
Now:        1492616333
Now micro:  1492616333.1153
Wait until: 1492616338
Now:        1492616337
Now micro:  1492616338.0001
```

Comment: 18 + 5 = 23  - I don't see the problem here. *"it always continues one second before the specified time"* - the clock keeps ticking (during and) after.

Comment: The third echo command should produce "Now: 1492614723", I think.

Comment: the server's internal clock keeps ticking; you're only delaying/interrupting the process using php; that's how I interpret it.

Comment: Peter's answer gave me correct result, check his answer.

Comment: @phinz, good luck and keep coding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time_sleep_until` uses `microtime`. If you'll use `microtime(true)` instead `time()` you'll get proper results:

```
Now:        1492615646.9312
Wait until: 1492615651.9312
Now:        1492615651.9313
```

`time()` and `microtime()` are different, see more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890155/994054

Proof:

```
...
time_sleep_until($waituntil);
echo "Now:        ".microtime(true)."\n";
echo "Now:        ".time()."\n";
```

gives me

```
Wait until: 1492615871
Now:        1492615871.0001
Now:        1492615870
```

I don't know exact reason why `time()` gives different result after you use `time_sleep_until`, you would have to dig down into PHP C code

Also it's worth to mention good alternative for `time_sleep_until()` is [usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

Comment: Peter, usleep almost the same as sleep, extept input parameter. My solution with sleep can't be used in this case.

Comment: @Viktor use `microtime` then

Comment: Your example with microtime gives me correct result, so you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Running this myself, I get the following result:

```
Now: 1492615301 
Wait until: 1492615306 
Now: 1492615306
```

What PHP version are you running on? I understand this function didn't play nice on Windows in the earlier versions (pre-5.3)

Comment: My PHP version is "PHP 5.6.29-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Dec 13 2016 16:02:08)" and I am on Debian 8. At least, I now know that it works as expected on your machine.

Comment: Interesting. If you are always using the same offset, perhaps using sleep() directly would be a better alternative?

Comment: I can't use sleep because of a time shift in loops, see my comment on Victor's answer. I will check the offset several times now.

Comment: Yeah I think your best bet is the microtime solution. I'm not sure why it works though. Possibly an issue with rounding? If you start in the middle of a tick, perhaps its enough to change the offset by  < 1s

Comment: Yes, it seems that `time` and `microtime` produce inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, better solution is to set timeout using `sleep` function? More you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php).

So, your code will look like this:

```
<?php
$now= time();
echo "Now: $now".PHP_EOL;
$sleepTimeout= 5;
echo "Sleep timeout: $sleepTimeout".PHP_EOL;
sleep($sleepTimeout);
echo "Time after sleep: ".time().PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Regards.

Comment: I wanted to use this to loop some commands every 5 seconds for logging and before I was using sleep but after some time, the time that php takes to execute the remaining commands in the loop matter and then there is a time shift. I thought `time_sleep_until` is the solution...