# php - getting date time using DateTime return different value from date() function

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, php-carbon

I am trying to get the current timestamp using Carbon or DateTime Class
I get wrong date but when I use date() function it return the correct date
I run the code on win server 2012
this is my code

```
dd([
    'Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s P")' => Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P'), 
    'DateTime()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s P")' => (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P'), 
    'date("Y-m-d H:i:s P")' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s P'),
    'date("Y-m-d H:i:s P",microtime(true))' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", microtime(true)),
    'date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", time())' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", time()),
    'Carbon::now()->getTimestamp()' => Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->getTimestamp(),
    'microtime()' => microtime(true),
    'time()' => time(),
]);
```

this is the output that I got

```
[
  "Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s P")" => "2018-06-25 22:41:59 +03:00"
  "DateTime()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s P")" => "2018-06-25 22:41:59 +03:00"
  "date("Y-m-d H:i:s P")" => "2018-06-19 11:59:22 +03:00"
  "date("Y-m-d H:i:s P",microtime(true))" => "2018-06-25 22:41:59 +03:00"
  "date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", time())" => "2018-06-19 11:59:22 +03:00"
  "Carbon::now()->getTimestamp()" => 1529955719
  "microtime()" => 1529955719.4257
  "time()" => 1529398762
]
```

the server time is the same as the value of date function

Comment: Hi, are you doing this on a local server, if so have you checked the server date time?

Comment: its not on local server

Comment: have you tried with: `$dt = Carbon::now();` and then use `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', $dt)->toDateTimeString();`

Comment: it cause Trailing data exception

Comment: probably a formatting issue; what if you run `"Y-m-d H:i:s P"` without the P, i.e. `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`

Comment: P used to show +03:00

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", microtime(true))`returns exact time DateTime() does. Is it wrong?

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s P", microtime(true)) return wrong date as will as the DateTime class

Comment: Altogether it seems that the problem may be due to and old bug with monotonic value of world time (jamie comment at http://php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php). Can you check what he’s saying and if it applies to your server?

Comment: Try to clear cache and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a configurations issue.
You have 2 ways to get UNIX-timestamp at PHP: `microtime(true)` and `time()`. **Carbon** and **DateTime** are using `microtime(true)` internally.

Here are some details referring to their implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890155/1921796

Comment: The information in the linked answer is awesome but... Can this explain a 6-day difference? (This is an honest question!)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's hard to debug without code and environment.
I think it's a bug in PHP for Windows Server 2012.
We can trace `microtime()` to function `get_time_func`: https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%40master/win32/time.c#33

Here you can see special if statement for Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8, looks like it has a bug or something like this.
If you can reproduce it would be helpful to report it at https://bugs.php.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the timezone at the top of the script?  You might be running into a session vs server timezone issue:

```
date_default_timezone_set ('whatevertimezone');
```

Comment: I do not think the timezone is the problem because timezone will change the time not the date 2018-06-19 - 2018-06-25 as shown in the question
despite that I tried to change the timezone the problem still appear

Answer (score -1):

can you try using

```
Carbon::today()
```

instead of using Carbon::now. It works for me .

Comment: if I want another way to get the correct date I can use date function but I have to fix the problem because each package uses DateTime or Carbon Class will get wrong date